# How to style (HTML) Monolog emails sent via Symfony Mailer

Tags: swiftmailer, monolog, symfony-mailer

Due to depreciation, I'm converting my *Monolog* email logging from *Swiftmailer* to *Symfony Mailer* (as recommended [here](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html)).

I have successfully completed the conversion and am receiving the emails.

However, with Swift Mailer all Monolog emails were nicely formatted (see [example](https://cdn.ourcodeworld.com/public-media/gallery/gallery-5b0eb3a6cc1d4.png)).
With Symfony Mailer, I only have a text version of the email.

Is there a way to get similar HTML output with Symfony Mailer?

By the way, I'm only using "symfony/mailer" and "symfony/monolog-bridge", not the full framework

**My code:**

```
$logger = new Logger('My Logger');

$transport = Transport::fromDsn('MYDSN');
$mailer = new Mailer($transport);

$message = (new Email())
    ->from(new Address('from@example.com', 'John Doe'))
    ->to(new Address('to@example.com', 'Jane Doe'))
    ->subject('My Subject');

$logger->pushHandler(
    new MailerHandler(
        $mailer,
        $message,
        Logger::ERROR
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, I had to add an HtmlFormatter (this was not necessary with Swift Mailer):

```
$logger->pushHandler(
    (new MailerHandler(
        $mailer,
        $message,
        Logger::ERROR
    )->setFormatter(new HtmlFormatter())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but if you configure the monolog-mailer via yaml only, this is what you need to add to get the nice html-formatting:

```
formatter:  monolog.formatter.html
content_type: text/html
```

(source: [How to configure Monolog to Email Errors](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_email.html))